# Python: Turn Nested List to Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I am trying to turn a nested list like this:
(Example list)

```
[['A','1','2','3'], ['B','4','5','6'],...]
```

To a dictionary that looks like this

```
{'A':'1','2','3','B': '4','5','6'}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```
lst = [['A','1','2','3'], ['B','4','5','6']]
{e[0]: e[1:] for e in lst}
```

This returns:

```
{'A': ['1', '2', '3'], 'B': ['4', '5', '6']}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can unpack the values? I don't want to keep the values as a list

Comment: @TrietNguyen 
What do you mean by "unpack"? Note that the example in your question (i.e. `{'A': '1','2','3','B': '4','5','6'}`) is unachievable because it is invalid Python syntax. That's not how dictionaries in Python work. Try entering `{'A':'1','2','3','B': '4','5','6'}` in your Python interpreter. You'll just get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.